# Expand sentry users table

Tags: laravel, relational-database, cartalyst-sentry

I expanded Sentry users table with few columns, but in this case I need help for *city_id* column. I did it in Laravel migrations. Now I need to make relationship between Sentry users and cities table.

I try to expand Sentry user Model and add *belongsTo*, but I cannot use it from Sentry::findUserById() like Sentry::findUserById()->with('city')

How can I expand Sentry user model with relationship to another table/model?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function city() {
        return $this->hasOne('City', 'id', 'city_id');
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to do something like this in your controller

```
$city = User::find($id)->city->name;
```

Or in your view you can do

```
{{ $user->city->name }}
```

Comment: I used Sentry not Laravel default User model

Comment: well then in the Sentry model add the method and instead of the query I gave you use $city = Sentry::findUserById($id)->city->name;